# iOS in app purchase receipt, missing recent transactions

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm able to read the receipts for in app purchase(in sandbox). I want to validate them for check canceled subscription. But problem is that when I subscribe for any product, i get '**transaction_id**' value but when i relaunch my app and get receipts again, my previous '**transaction_id**' value is missing. I want my subscribed '**transaction_id**' showing in my receipt array always.

Here is my code :

```
func receiptValidation() {

    let receiptFileURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL
    let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptFileURL!)
    let recieptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let jsonDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["receipt-data" : recieptString! as AnyObject, "password" : "My-App-Shared-Secret" as AnyObject]
    do {
        let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let verifyReceiptURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        let storeURL = URL(string: verifyReceiptURL)!
        var storeRequest = URLRequest(url: storeURL)
        storeRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        storeRequest.httpBody = requestData

        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: storeRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                print("=======>",jsonResponse)
                if let date = self?.getExpirationDateFromResponse(jsonResponse as! NSDictionary) {
                    print(date)
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print(parseError)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}

func getExpirationDateFromResponse(_ jsonResponse: NSDictionary) -> Date? {

    if let receiptInfo: NSArray = jsonResponse["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {

        let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

        // Get last receipt
        print("LAST RECEIPT INFORMATION \n",lastReceipt)

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale

        if let expiresDate = lastReceipt["expires_date"] as? String {
            print("\n   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = \(expiresDate)")
            return formatter.date(from: expiresDate)
        }

        return nil
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned `transaction_id` in your question, but there is no reference to it in the code you posted. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't rely on `transaction_id` to check on canceled subscriptions.

[As per Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) (search for "transaction_id"), it can change over time:

> For a transaction that restores a previous transaction, this value is
>   different from the transaction identifier of the original purchase
>   transaction. In an auto-renewable subscription receipt, a new value
>   for the transaction identifier is generated every time the
>   subscription automatically renews or is restored on a new device.

Instead, it would be better to use the latest `expires_date` from the `latest_receipt_info` array.
Compare it with today's date to check if the subscription is expired or not.

---

This field may also support your use case: `auto_renew_status`

As in (from Apple's validation JSON response):

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "environment": "Sandbox",
  "receipt": {...},
  "latest_receipt_info": [{...}],
  "latest_receipt": "...",
  "pending_renewal_info": [
    {
      "auto_renew_product_id": "<yourAutoRenewProductID>",
      "original_transaction_id": "<transacionID>",
      "product_id": "<yourProductID>",
      "auto_renew_status": "1" <<=== This one here
    }
  ]
}
```

> "1" - Subscription will renew at the end of the current subscription
>   period.
>
> "0" - Customer has turned off automatic renewal for their
>   subscription.

Keep in mind:

> This key is only present for auto-renewable subscription receipts, for
>   active or expired subscriptions. The value for this key should not be
>   interpreted as the customer’s subscription status. You can use this
>   value to display an alternative subscription product in your app, for
>   example, a lower level subscription plan that the customer can
>   downgrade to from their current plan.

---

If you REALLY need to know the original `transaction_id`, then there is the `original_transaction_id` field. Again from Apple:

> This value is the same for all receipts that have been generated for a
>   specific subscription. This value is useful for relating together
>   multiple iOS 6 style transaction receipts for the same individual
>   customer’s subscription.

But based on what you wrote, that seems like overcomplicating things. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`